Почему не работает scanf?

Только начинаю изучать C++ и уже со старта проблемы. Написал всё в точности, как было в обучающем видео.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("sum = %d\n", a+b);

    return 0;
}


Потому что Visual Studio считает эту функцию небезопасной #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS в начало файла. Либо scanf_s.

@evo Спасибо, помогло. А почему он считает её небезопасной?

Почему небезопасной? А что будет, например, при char s[2]; scanf("%s",s); и вводе чтотооченьдлинное?

Скорее всего, вы пишите свой код в файле с расширением .cpp. Компилятор MSVC генерирует программу в соответствии с типом файла: файл .cpp через Vicual C++, а файл с расширением .c - через Visual C. Так как в вашем коде я вижу код на чистом С (кроме библиотеки iostream и пространства имен std), советую поменять расширение вашего файла с .cpp на .c (тогда следует ещё и удалить include <iostream> и using namespace std;).
P.S. Следует ещё заменить scanf на scanf_s.
Если же вам нужно иметь писать возможность и на С++, то как evo, советую использовать #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS и scanf_s (лучше всего вместе).
P.S. Если же вам нужно писать лишь на чистом Си, то лучше использовать int
main(void) {}, а не int main() {}

Изменение файла на .c не отменит сообщения о небезопасности scanf.

@Harry, а автор его принял (lol)

@Harry, вижу, что вы правы. Я не фанат Visual Studio, поэтому не помню этой особенности. Лучше заменить в файле с расширением .с scanf на scanf_s.
